# Google Analytics show different data from January now than it did last month

Tags: google, google-analytics

Last week I took sessions and user data from google analytics for January 2019. This week I look at the same month, and the figures are different.

Can anyone explain to me why it changed?

I've checked that its 100% of GA sessions and it is so that's why I'm confused with the changes.

Comment: I know you checked that you hadn't segmented the original data, but there are other things that might account for the discrepancy. Are you looking at the same view? If you have a view that filters out specific traffic then you'd see different figures. Or possibly an advanced filter on the data you're looking at. Have you, or anyone else with access, imported any data that may have added users and sessions for that time period?